# Carousel with sliding background, fixed image and sliding foreground

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello dear dev community,

I have to develop a boostrap-4 carousel with a background image (B) and a text (T) for every slide and a fixed image (F) in the middle, so that the image B slides behind the image F, while the text T slides in front of the image F.

I tried to do it using z-index property without success. Here is my jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/4tvb6yuj/1/

Here an example of a "carousel-item":

```html
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="...">
        <div style="z-index: 60" class="carousel-caption d-none d-block">
          <h5>(1) This text should <br/> 
              slide in front of  <br/> 
              the dog image</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The image F is placed inside the "carousel-inner", out and after of any "carousel-item":

```html
      <div style="position: relative; top: 30px; left:10px;">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/120/180"/>
      </div>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. You can stack the whole `.carousel-item` in front of the image or in the back, but you cannot put one item (`background-image`) in back and the other item (`text`) in the front because both elements have the same parent.

You have to change markup and JavaScript to have two moving containers.

```
<div>
    <div class="background-image"></div><!-- this will get moved by javascript -->
    <div class="dog-image"></div><!-- this is static -->
    <div class="text"></div><!-- this will get moved by javascript -->
</div>
```

It would be better to change the design. If I would really need to implement this I would probably not use Bootstrap carousel and create my bespoke one to move two containers.

Comment: In fact this is what I feared, only I needed confirmation from someone with more experience in this field. So I'll try with this solution. Do you know any similar example that I can follow? Thank you again for your help

Comment: Sorry I have no example that i can show you. I created a similar thing years ago and had some issues with flicker in some browsers. If you cannot change the design test with as many browsers as you can. If you have problems post your code and I will try to help.

Comment: No problem. The customer has changed his mind. Thank you very much